# Is there an easy way to overwrite Backtrader IB broker live data feed?

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, backtrader

I am working on [Backtrader](https://www.backtrader.com/) using IB Broker, And i need to overwrite data reciever function so instead of using Backtrader ibstore to get live data, It use my own data service (its just a simple socket connection that returns IB data for now).
Unfortunately it is not documented well enough and the code itself is comlicated.
I need to know where should i put my code.
There are several places i have found but no idea which place is the best and works ofcourse:

- _load(self) function at ibdata
- reqMktData function at ibstore
- realtimeBar function at ibstore

Note: I need to use other IB stuff so i don't want to disable IB totaly, just the live data stuff

Comment: That's not trivial. Sorry.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.